# Selecting text from terminal doesn't copy it to another terminal

Tags: linux, troubleshooting, clipboard, urxvt

I use arch linux and rxvt-unicode, my window manager is bspwm. If i select text in terminal i can go to a gui program and paste it with middle mouse button. Likewise if i select text in a gui program i can paste it in terminal with middle click. But for some reason if i select text in terminal and then go on another terminal window (or even the same) i can't paste it.

What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 0):

for selecting text from terminal use **mouse+left click hold** and move it

**copy** selected text from terminal by pressing keys = **ctrl+shift+c**

**paste** copied text on terminal by pressing
keys = **ctrl+shift+v**